# how can i send the php value through function js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am doing this But not its not taking value what i am doing wrong here.
 its returning me the error .why this happening how can we send the php value.why its not getting the value from the php and how we can access this through the function.

code What I am trying to do.
code is given below:

```
<td align="center" class="view_cart_middle1"><?php echo form_input(array('name' => $i.'[qty]', 'value' => $items['qty'], 'maxlength' => '3', 'size' => '5' ,'autocomplete' => 'off','class' => 'form-control view-cart-qty','readonly' => 'readonly', 'onclick' => "get_aproved(". $items['rowid'] .",". $items['qty'] .")", 'onkeyup' => "checkcart(this.value)','id'=>'quantity')"); ?></td>
```

They didnt get the value which is from php.i ma newbe here so please help me related this

Comment: this is in a PHP file, not a js one, right?

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: yes.. its a php file

Comment: why the single quote on start & end? can you provide complete line of code. try without single quote on start & end.

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Parsing Error

Message: syntax error, unexpected 'rowid' (T_STRING), expecting ')'

Comment: see i updated the code..

Comment: Update all information in the question. Not in the comments. Edit your question and paste the error in it.

Comment: updated ..@ Neil

Comment: You can't nest `<?php ?>`. It should be `'onclick="get_aproved('.$items['rowid'].', '.$items['qty'].')"'`. Also, doesn't make sense to `echo` something inside function parameters.

Comment: do you have tested your code with modified one

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<td align="center" class="view_cart_middle1"><?php echo form_input(array('name' => $i.'[qty]', 'value' => $items['qty'], 'maxlength' => '3', 'size' => '5' ,'autocomplete' => 'off','class' => 'form-control view-cart-qty','readonly' => 'readonly', 'onclick' => "get_aproved(". $items['rowid'] .",". $items['qty'] .")", 'onkeyup' => "checkcart(this.value)','id'=>'quantity')")); ?></td>
```

one ')' was missing